# Tagging questions about North American major leagues

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed some questions (5 at the moment) about generic contract issues, etc., tagged all of [nfl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfl), [nba](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nba), [mlb](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mlb), and [nhl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl).

Is there a better way to tag these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Under [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances) and/or [transaction](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction) given the contract issue/characteristic.

As for the major North American league tags, we have three options:

1. leave as is (why not?)
2. create a tag that encompasses the four major North American leagues (why?)
3. **eliminate the tags of the four major North American leagues from the question
   (which wouldn't take away from the question itself)** <-- chose this option

Comment: I mean they're tagged with all 4 tags at once; they're not asking about a specific sport.

Comment: but if we eliminate the tags from the tag section and just mention the leagues in the body of the question, will that question come up in a search just like it would if it had all 4 tags?
for example if we have the tags then I can search for nfl using "nfl" and "[nfl]". So without tags such questions will not fall under any these major sports categories, and won't be seen when a user searcher by categories. 
Why can't we just have a tag to represent all these sports at once?

Comment: @alamoot `major-leagues` is a better suggestion than `big4`, which appears to be colloquial. The tag-wiki will clear any confusion as to how the tag is to be used, but note that users [may not read the tag-wiki](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/460/should-wages-tag-be-renamed#comment1135_460).

Comment: @alamoot to answer your first question, I did the search query "is:q nfl mlb nba nhl" and [these are the results](http://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+nfl+mlb+nba+nhl)

Comment: @alamoot **Why can't we just have a tag to represent all these sports at once?** You state that you anticipate more questions specific to those four pro leagues will be asked. I am hard-pressed to think of a question that would not be better off being asked by asking about it's specific league, instead of encompassing the four. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @edmastermind29 to avoid asking a question a general question 4 times. For example  [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/in-what-way-do-professional-athletes-mlb-nhl-nfl-nba-get-paid). Instead of asking how athletes get paid in each league, the general idea is asked for all leagues.

Comment: @alamoot Sure, it's a general question, but it borderlines toward being too broad. The specifics in which how athletes get paid in each sport is different according to the answer. I thought about that question also, but [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/do-minor-league-baseball-clubs-pay-the-players) is where specificity was brought out.

Comment: Added the major-leagues tag for this question https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/north-american-major-league-teams-with-most-championships-won-on-the-road-before

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question also brings to mind whether or not it's necessary to have a [discipline-agnostic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline-agnostic) or something like that? Honestly I am not sure if it says much more than [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances) or [contracts](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) already does...

Comment: discipline-agnostic would be a meta tag. IE it sets parameters for the question not context.

Comment: `discipline-agnostic` = no tag of a given sport.